# HP ProBook 4540s CD/DVD Drive cannot Read Disks

Tags: dvd, disk-drive

I seem to have a problem with the CD/DVD drive on my HP ProBook 4540s laptop. I cannot get it to read any disks. Normally, I would say that this is a hardware issue, but whenever I put a disk that previously could be read in the drive, it starts to make noise like it is trying to to read the disk but cannot and AnyDVD HD seems to be able to retrieve disk information with some struggle. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my laser was a little bit dirty. Cleaning the laser with some rubbing alcohol on a Q-tip solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a HP ProBook 4540s and experienced the same problem: Inserting a disk would prompt the autoplay function but the disk drive would show 0 bytes on file. The disk drive would also begin working then stop repeatedly - trying to work but unsuccessful.

SOLVED BY - cleaning the laser with an ear bud and water + blowing out any dust that may have accumulated.

Comment: Pure alcohol is better than tap water for cleaning the lens of an optical drive. I suggest that you edit your answer and replace the word "water" with "alcohol".

Comment: Yes, it's my understanding that repeatedly cleaning the laser with water will actually do more harm than good. In the future, stick with alcohol. I've had this issue arise several times since posting this question, so the same may possibly be true of your laser as well.